# bash: ./shelllab2.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, git, shell, scripting

I am running shell scripting program using git bash on windows 10.

I am sure I had created my file here then also getting this error.

```
bash: ./shelllab2.sh: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Check first where you are when you try to access that script:

```sh
pwd
ls -alrth
```

You will see if `./shelllab2.sh` is indeed here.